# Display multiple image format

Tags: vb.net, image

I have one folder that contains images with multiple format like `.jpg`, `.pdf`, `.png`

They are named `1.jpg`, `2.pdf`, `3.png` like that.

While I enter `1` or `2` or `3` in text box then I want to display that image in picture box.

My Problem is that it show only `jpg` image file not showing `pdf` or `png`

```
Dim ImagePath As String = "E:\" & Val(TxtReceiptNo.Text) & ".jpg"
Dim img1 As Bitmap
Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("E:\" & Val(TxtReceiptNo.Text) & ".jpg")
img1 = New Bitmap(ImagePath)
PicBx.ImageLocation = ImagePath
PicBx.Image = newImage
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question, it will be pretty difficult to help you otherwise. And you do realise .pdf is not an image format....?

Comment: Dim ImagePath As String = "E:\Net Project\Voting\FJCCI\FJCCI\" & Val(TxtReceiptNo.Text) & ".jpg"
                    Dim img1 As Bitmap
                    Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("E:\Net Project\Voting\FJCCI\FJCCI\" & Val(TxtReceiptNo.Text) & ".jpg")

                    img1 = New Bitmap(ImagePath)
                    PicBx.ImageLocation = ImagePath
                    PicBx.Image = newImage

Comment: Please add it to the question (use the code sample icon) as it's pretty difficult to read as a comment

Answer (score 1):

Image can't handle PDF. Image displays BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG, and TIFF. You'll need to add the ADOBE dll's to your project and work with those to display the PDF at the size you want.

Also, you need to look for each image format type you want to process.

This code is from a project I'm working on. It opens PNG, JPG, and PNG files and places them into a picturebox contained in a flowlayoutpanel on a form. (Me.picpanel = New System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel())

```
      For Each fi As FileInfo In DirInfo.GetFiles
            If Not (fi.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) = FileAttributes.Hidden Then
                If fi.Extension = ".png" Or fi.Extension = ".jpg" Or fi.Extension = ".bmp" Then
                        .Tag = fi.FullName
                    MyImageList.Add(fi.FullName)

                End If
            End If

        Next



        Dim a As String

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try


    Try

        For Each MyImage In MyImageList

            Dim Width As Integer = 700
            Dim sourceImage As Image = Image.FromFile(MyImage)
            Dim X As Integer = sourceImage.Width
            Dim Y As Integer = sourceImage.Height

            Dim fullSizeImg As Image = Image.FromFile(MyImage)
            Dim P As New PictureBox

            P.Tag = fullSizeImg
            P.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            P.Size = New Size(200, 200)
            P.Image = fullSizeImg
            picpanel.Controls.Add(P)

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: can you tell me how to create a set up file in vb.net project with database and excel file

Comment: @Raj, Sorry, but no. I've never needed to work with databases or Excel when using VB, only MS Word.

Answer (score 1):

Since you concatenate the file name and since you always put ".jpg" as the file suffix, only existing jpg files will be shown.
Instead you have to look for existing files and showing them when you found one:

For instance:

```
    Dim ImagePath As String = "E:\"
    Dim SearchPattern As String = TxtReceiptNo.Text & ".*"

    Dim files As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(ImagePath, SearchPattern)

    If files IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each file As String In files
            ... (your code for showing pictures goes here)
        Next file
    End If
```

Comment: thnx For Ur Sugg